# Displaying the data source in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, datasource, ssrs-2008-r2, sqldatasource

How do I return and display the data source in SSRS?

I've got multiple data sources in the report in addition to Live vs. Test systems. How do I output/display a string with the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in function to get data source names in an expression.

Interestingly, you can use an expression to define a connection string. So you could use that same expression elsewhere on the report.

I was hoping there was a way to access them through Custom Code. The only approach I could find though is to query the [Report Server database](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/42440a6b-c5b1-4acc-9632-d608d1c40a5c).

Comment: I pulled the elements and added them to my data set at the end of the query -- as the only work around (that doesn't involve tons of code) i had hoped there was some kind of function call i wasn't aware off

Comment: Good idea. They could be in their own little one-row dataset too.